# Looking for a way to "parametrize" .click() in jquery

Tags: jquery

As I'm far from being even a jquery newbie (I took over bunch of code and now need a way to figure out how it's working and how to improve it), I have the following codes:

jQuery:

```
$("#button1").click(function() {$("#btnbutton1:first-child").click();});
$("#button2").click(function() {$("#btnbutton2:first-child").click();});
$("#button3").click(function() {$("#btnbutton3:first-child").click();});
```

HTML:

```
<DIV class=hiddenButtons>
<div id="btnbutton1"><SpotfireControl id="2e21a4f7e5794ad98b0048672462a290" /></div>
<div id="btnbutton2"><SpotfireControl id="0f8b33874ec64a4285721f11b42373db" /></div>
<div id="btnbutton3"><SpotfireControl id="0ae43a8ccc784fa192dbc360431a912f" /></div>
</DIV>
[....]
        <td id="button1" class="button-group active">Label1</td>
        <td id="button2" class="button-group">Label2</td>
        <td id="button3" class="button-group">Label3</td>
[....]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a way to optimze a jquery to a one line similar to that:

```
$("#"+param).click(function() {$("#btn"+param+":first-child").click();});
```

In the other words: is there a way to shorten this jQuery to one line which after clicking object in  pass it's id to jQuery and then do the click action? Asking as my jQuery will end up with around ~20 of such lines, and I figured it will be clearer to have just one to solve them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you're trying to follow here is known as Don't Repeat Yourself, or DRY.

To achieve this you can use the common classes on the `td` elements to group them, along with `data` attributes to add some custom metadata to each of them to change the click event behaviour. Something like this:

```html
<div class="hiddenButtons">
  <div id="btnbutton1">
    <SpotfireControl id="2e21a4f7e5794ad98b0048672462a290" />
  </div>
  <div id="btnbutton2">
    <SpotfireControl id="0f8b33874ec64a4285721f11b42373db" />
  </div>
  <div id="btnbutton3">
    <SpotfireControl id="0ae43a8ccc784fa192dbc360431a912f" />
  </div>
</div>

<td class="button-group active" data-target="#btnButton1">Label1</td>
<td class="button-group" data-target="#btnButton2">Label2</td>
<td class="button-group" data-target="#btnButton2">Label3</td>
```

```js
$(".button-group").click(function() {
  var selector = $(this).data('target');
  $(selector).find(':first-child').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.button-group').on('click', function(){
 $('#btn'+$(this).attr('id')).click();
})
```

Try this...

Comment: You can replace `$(this).attr('id')` with just `this.id`

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this (ES6)

```js
$(".button-group").click(function() {
  $(`#btn${this.id} SpotfireControl`).click();}
);



$("SpotfireControl").click(function() {
  alert(`id: ${this.id}`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=hiddenButtons>
  <div id="btnbutton1">
    <SpotfireControl id="2e21a4f7e5794ad98b0048672462a290" />
  </div>
  <div id="btnbutton2">
    <SpotfireControl id="0f8b33874ec64a4285721f11b42373db" />
  </div>
  <div id="btnbutton3">
    <SpotfireControl id="0ae43a8ccc784fa192dbc360431a912f" />
  </div>
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="button1" class="button-group active">Label1</td>
    <td id="button2" class="button-group">Label2</td>
    <td id="button3" class="button-group">Label3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or with VanillaJS

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('button-group')) {
    const evt = new Event("click", {bubbles: true});
    document
      .getElementById(`btn${e.target.id}`)
      .getElementsByTagName('SPOTFIRECONTROL')[0]
      .dispatchEvent(evt);
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
  if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'SPOTFIRECONTROL') {
    alert(`id: ${e.target.id}`);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class=hiddenButtons>
  <div id="btnbutton1">
    <SpotfireControl id="2e21a4f7e5794ad98b0048672462a290" />
  </div>
  <div id="btnbutton2">
    <SpotfireControl id="0f8b33874ec64a4285721f11b42373db" />
  </div>
  <div id="btnbutton3">
    <SpotfireControl id="0ae43a8ccc784fa192dbc360431a912f" />
  </div>
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="button1" class="button-group active">Label1</td>
    <td id="button2" class="button-group">Label2</td>
    <td id="button3" class="button-group">Label3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```